# How to properly install scala metals lsp in spacemacs

Tags: scala, spacemacs, scala-metals

The title says it all, I want to install scala metals LSP in spacemacs, I did try the official metals/spacemacs tutorials without success:

- https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/emacs.html
- https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/scala/README.html

Did anyone manage to get scala-metals to work in spacemacs?